# Color octomap file not displayed by octovis

Tags: ros, octomap, octovis

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have created an octomap , the file name is color_server_map_000.cot, but the map is not displayed in octovis giving error "cannot open file". Please help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12445/color-octomap-file-not-displayed-by-octovis/) by [Suraj](https://answers.ros.org/users/1570/suraj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-12-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2012-01-17**:
The 000 part of the name suggests that no pointclouds have been included. Could you post the filesize please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What and which versions are you using to generate the file? [octomap](http://www.ros.org/wiki/octomap) and [octovis](http://www.ros.org/wiki/octomap) released in ROS don't have color support yet (based on OctoMap 1.2).

If you use OctoMap trunk (the upcoming 1.4 version) there is now improved file support and color information. However, .cot files are not officially supported. You can convert them to the ".ot" file format with the "convert_octree" binary. octovis in trunk will then display the file correctly (you might have to enter the correct resolution manually in the file header because .cot did not store it).

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2011-12-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2011-12-27**:
To save a .bt file from your code: tree.writeBinary(filename). To save a .ot with the new functionality in trunk: tree.write(filename). Please have a look at the documentation or convert_octree.cpp as sample code.

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2011-12-27**:
Please update your question to clarify what exactly you are trying to do with which code. It's hard to guess what goes wrong in your case. If convert_octree gives you an error then your ran it on the wrong file or it is corrupted.

**Comment by [Suraj](https://answers.ros.org/users/1570/suraj/) on 2011-12-26**:
I have tried with both ROS version and from the Octomap trunk but the files converted using convert_octree dosen't give any result either. Isn't there any way to generate .ot or .bt files directly. Some help will really be appreciated!

**Comment by [Suraj](https://answers.ros.org/users/1570/suraj/) on 2011-12-25**:
thanks for the reply.  I tried converting the .cot file to .ot file as you pointed out , but i'm getting an error that "Input file stream not "good" ". Can you explain how to edit the header?